# Changing Microsoft OneNote 2013 Proofing Language

Tags: microsoft-onenote, proofing

I have a collection of MS OneNote sections that spell check in English US. All I want to do is change this - globally - to English UK.

If I select a section, and check the Proofing Language - it shows up as English US. I can change it to English UK - but it appears only a section at a time - i.e. I have to manually go to each OneNote page, select it and change the Proofing Language to English UK.

This is no fun, when:

a) I have hundreds of pages/sections

and

b) I have all O/S (Windows 7) Region and Language settings set to English UK

....it appears that OneNote 2013 completely ignores the default Regional Language settings, and just proofs everything in English US.

Any help would be much appreciated, as everything I have read so far, tells me that OneNote takes it's default settings from the O/S Regional Language defaults - which is plainly rubbish!